# Does pry work on Rails 2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm looking for a good solution to debug my application(written on Rails 2) and I found pry very helpful. How can I use it in a Rails 2 app, tried and it doesn't seem to be working? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Pry is a general-purpose Ruby console/debugger. Rails is just a Ruby framework. Why wouldn't it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script/console --irb=pry
```

see: https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Setting-up-Rails-or-Heroku-to-use-Pry

Answer (score 1):

Add pry to gemfile:

```
gem 'pry'
```

Run `bundle install`

Then to launch a console with pry:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec pry -r config/environment.rb
```

Or add a `binding.pry` somewhere in your code as a breakpoint.